Running shell commands in Jenkins kubernetes container
Im just trying to execute shell commands in a Jenkins kubernetes container from a pipeline. Getting the below error
11:30:35  cp: can't stat '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/builds/<project>/durable-19885294/script.sh': No such file or directory
11:30:35  sh: can't create /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/builds/<project>/durable-19885294/output.txt: nonexistent directory
  sh: can't create /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/builds/<project>/durable-19885294/jenkins-result.txt.tmp: nonexistent directory
  mv: can't rename '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/builds/<project>/durable-19885294/jenkins-result.txt.tmp': No such file or directory
11:35:42  process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/builds/<project>/durable-19885294

My understanding is that the pipeline is executed as Jenkins user and not root.
Please guide me on best possible way to run shell commands as super user inside Jenkins kubernetes pod
Many thanks!
